# How to make expand-btn disappear when the description is less than 234px and when the min-width is 1280px

Tags: css, sveltekit

I'm trying to implement a feature where a button disappears under specific conditions. Specifically, I want the button to vanish when the description's height is under a maximum of 234 pixels, and the screen width reaches or exceeds 1280 pixels.

[example in replexample in repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/6b88d85c828f46e690b85f0b01f355ef?version=4.2.2)

I'm trying to make this:

[mangadex example](https://mangadex.org/title/40bc649f-7b49-4645-859e-6cd94136e722/dragon-ball)

Comment: why even to use width or pixels to hide it? you can simply hide it using css when it have text showless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the block will be rendered if the condition in the `#if` block is false. In this case, it means that the button will not be rendered if `descriptionVisible` is true.

```
    {#if !descriptionVisible}
    <button class="expand-btn" on:click={toggleDescription}>
        {descriptionVisible ? 'Show less' : '...more'}
    </button>
    {/if}
```

if the purpose is to only hide after expending, then better not render at all